# Why is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \log(X_i)}{n} = \overline{log X}$

Tags: logarithms, statistical-inference

Why is $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \log(X_i)}{n} = \overline{log X}$$ ($X_i$ are i.i.d samples)

Comment: what is your $X$?

Comment: @Did: Isn't it? Given samples $X_i$, the mean of their logs is certainly what was written, isn't it?

Comment: @MPW If the RHS is defined as the LHS, they are equal and the question is absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the notation convention. If a function $f$ is defined for all possible values $X_i$ in your sample, then
$$\overline
{f(X)} = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i).$$

Comment: Did you mean $f(X_i)$ instead of $X_i$ in the sum on the right side?

Comment: @MPW of course, thanks for the catch.